# How to reload div content without reloading page in asp

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, setinterval, reload

I have a div in a content page in asp.net. I want to reload only the div every 2 seconds automatically. But it should not reload the entire page. I am not much aware about jquery and ajax. Explain the solution step by step..

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Btw, look into Update Panels.

Comment: Update Panel will help. Have a look here [Update Panel](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f50501/use-updatepanel-control-in-Asp-Net/) and make sure to try something before asking for a solution.